# Apply Zombie Walk Animation : Unity3d

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I am learning unity and i just wanted to know about how we can apply zombie walk animation through script? 
I am having zombie 3d model with no animation. I want to know that is it possible to animate thoes 3d model by using script. ??

Because i have tried to animate them with 3ds max software but i failed to apply animation on that 3d model. because it requires more practice.

So is there any other way to make my zombie walk.?

I have tried zombie available on Mixamo : http://www.mixamo.com/catalog/motions/FREE-creeping-zombie-walk-loop-walking-86

But i want other types of zombie . even i don't want to purchase.

Thanks to all of you for supporting me and helping me till now..

Hope for the best solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good animations are hard to produce algorithmically. The only good ones I've seen are from Natural Motion (http://www.naturalmotion.com/) and they're totally out of reach for an indie dev.

Your best bet is to buy animations which you can then rig to multiple characters. You've already seen Mixamo, but there are some other interesting animations/controllers in Unity's asset store. Check https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/3853 for example.

Comment: This is also a great animation pack, and is free: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19991

Answer (score 0):

To add a animation through script you just need to create a variable and assign that to the character. Or use navigation components then bake the scene.